# What is the difference between the PHP functions iconv_strlen, mb_strlen and strlen?

Tags: php, function

What is the difference between the iconv_strlen, mb_strlen and strlen functions?

And what is each used for in the real world?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference of `strlen()` to `mb_strlen()` is, that the second respects multibyte characters. This means, that this is the real character count. The first one assumes, that the string is always in ascii, what also means, that it always returns the size in bytes (very useful when handling binary "strings").

As far as I can see `iconv_strlen()` is quite similar to `mb_strlen()`, but fails on bad character sequences, in contrast to `mb_strlen()`, that just ignores them. And it uses the `iconv`-library (obviously ;)).